# RSelenium error when using sendKeysToElement in Chrome

Tags: javascript, r, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium to remotely interact with a webpage in Chrome:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://database.globalreporting.org/search")
textBox <- remDr$findElement("id", "search-report-field")
textBox$sendKeysToElement("Company Name")
```

Specifically, I want to be able to send keystrokes to the textbox on this page labeled "Search by organization name" (the textbox id is "search-report-field"). I am able to perform various actions on the element (highlight, click, etc...), but sendKeysToElement throws the following error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
         Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         class: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Any idea what might be causing the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys need to be given as a list for example:

```
textBox$sendKeysToElement(list("some Text", key = "enter"))
```

For your example:

```
library(RSelenium)
# running
#  docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.53.0
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://database.globalreporting.org/search")
textBox <- remDr$findElement("id", "search-report-field")
textBox$sendKeysToElement(list("Company Name"))
```

Comment: That fixed it - thanks! I see now that's how it's done in the RSelenium documentation. Thanks so much for your help.